# How to set values of angular custom input components (control value accessors) from parent?

Tags: angular

We have the ability to set values (in case if needed) for native input elements such as checkboxes, text input etc..

It will be like this :

```
<input type="text" [value]="customValue">
```

In this way we can bind custom values to the native input elements.

How can I achieve similar result with a custom input element implemented with control value accessor?

For example consider this custom Input component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-custom-input',
  templateUrl: './child-custom-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChildCustomInputComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class ChildCustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  _value: boolean;

  onChanged: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  constructor() {}

  writeValue(value: any) {
    this._value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChanged = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setValue(value) {
    this._value = value;
    this.onChanged(value);
    this.check.emit(value);
  }
```

Following  is from the parent component:

```
// parent-component.html

<child-custom-input [value]="customInputValue"> </child-custom-input>
```

How can I achieve such a result?

Like setting a default/ initial value from the parent component to the custom child input component.

```
// child-custom-input.component.html

<input type="text" placeholder="Input something..." (input)="setValue($event.target.value)">
```

Or could be something like a checkbox. The only thing required is to set value from the parent component to this custom child input component.

```
// child-custom-input.component.html

<input type="checkbox" (input)="setValue($event.target.checked)">
```

Comment: Can you share child-custom-input html code?

Comment: It will be a template for a simple input element. With an input method on it setValue($event.target.value). Don't worry about that.

Comment: Have you tried Input property binding to set child component value?

Comment: The truth is that the real input element is inside the custom child component. What I want  to achieve is that I want to set the input value of this custom child component from the parent component such that the real input element (inside custom child component) will receive that value. I've tried to set via input binding, but I don't think that is the proper way. It would be better if we can achieve something like this <input type="checkbox" [value]="customValue">.
It would be great if you can suggest something.!

Comment: Send me your suggestions. Will be great if you write some code.

Comment: ControlValueAccessor is bridge between Angular forms API and a native element in the DOM. If you are not using angular form along with custom form control. Then using input property binding is the only way to set child component value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215410/discussion-between-mex-and-chellappan-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do so, you need to also define an `@Input() value: any` property and the appropriate *getter* and *setter* in your ChildCustomInputComponent.

```
export class ChildCustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
.
.
.

  //The internal data model
  private innerValue: any = '';

  //get accessor
  @Input()
  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  }

  //set accessor including call the onchange callback
  set value(v: any) {
    if (v !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = v;
      this.onChangeCallback(v);
    }
  }

}
```

That way you should be able to use the ChildCustomInputComponent and define their value property from any parent component like this:

```
<custom-input name="myCustomComponent" [value]="'Any value here'"></custom-input>
```

For further clarification please check the following working example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/zNOYwrLsszY54DDL